# iOS Layout : How to Handle issue with auto height of UIView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

I have UIView that needs to be in width like the screen width but proportionally to that width his height to be auto for different iPhone device. Any way to handle this with constraints in storyboards?

Thanks

Comment: create an Aspect Ratio constraint

Answer (score 0):

For width, you just pin the leading and trailing edges of the view to the superview.

For height you can make it proportional to the width by using the Aspect Ratio constraint. e.g. If you set it to 1:1 then the height will equal the width. You can change the ratio to make the height larger or smaller relative to the width.

Answer (score 0):

Open your story board-> select Viewcontroler from left pane -> Editor- >Resolve Auto Lauout Issues -> Add missing constraints. thats it, `try this, this will help you or set constraint manually as @Rory suggest`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two way you can do it.
First you can use aspect ratio, just control drag from your view diagonal to the same view and select aspect ratio. If it match your requirements thats fine.

The second option is ctrl drag from the view to superview and choose Equal Heights. After than go to the size inspector of the view and double click ok the new constraint. Make sure the first item is your view.height and the second one is superview.height, if it's not click on any of those and select reverse first and second item. After that just select multiplayer to what you need, for. example 0.5 means the height will be half of the superview height.
You can change the second item to superview width so the view height will be half of superview's width if the multiplayer is 0.5.

With with pin your view to top, leading and trailing edges of the superview.